# illegal mix of collations Error - all tables and columns are same collection

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I want to run a procedure I got this error:

```
 General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_persian_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' (SQL: CALL SP_Fetch_Menu_Notifications())
```

But all my tables and columns are same collection,`utf8_general_ci`.

my database collection is `utf8_general_ci`.

all variable string collections inside procedure are `varchar(255)` .

Comment: what is in CALL SP_Fetch_Menu_Notifications() ? see hich line comapres varchar and check where bith siedes come from.

Comment: Check all collations - server, connection, database, table, column. Server claims that `utf8_persian_ci` is somewhere used.

Comment: Usually this occurs when you have a raw string somewhere in your query and it is that string which is being interpreted as `utf8_persian_ci`. The workaround is to specify a collation for it.

Comment: @Nick I have not using any implicit collection to my queries.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian but do you have any raw strings in the query?

Comment: @Akina How to check ` server, connection` collection?

Comment: @Nick, yes,  `SELECT perm_id INTO _Perm_id FROM Tb_Permissions WHERE alias='MANAGE_REPORT_BUGS' LIMIT 1;`

Comment: So try `SELECT perm_id INTO _Perm_id FROM Tb_Permissions WHERE alias='MANAGE_REPORT_BUGS' COLLATE utf8_general_ci LIMIT 1` (assuming `alias` is utf8_general_ci)

Comment: Check `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'col%';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'cha%';`.